# Why doesn't my python program click or move the mouse?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import numpy as np
import pyautogui
import cv2
import time
import sys
from PIL import ImageGrab
import directkeys
import pyscreenshot

cords = [0,1800, 160,1040]
mousepos = pyautogui.position()
print(mousepos)
green = (106,199,0)
low_red = np.array([161,155,84])
high_red = np.array([179,255,255])
screen = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=cords)
screenrgb = screen.convert('RGB')

while True:
    for y in range(screenrgb.height):
        for x in range(screenrgb.width):
            r, g , b = screenrgb.getpixel(x1,y2)
            if (r,g,b) == green:
                pyautogui.click(screenrgb.getpixel(x1,y2))
```

This is my code, but I fail to see why the program doesn't click or move the mouse to the desired position

Answer (score 0):

You are using `x1` and `y1` without defining it in your code.

If you wanted to use `x` and `y` if you just defined it in the `for` clause,

You should use `x`, `y` instead of `x1` and `y1`.

```
import numpy as np
import pyautogui
import cv2
import time
import sys
from PIL import ImageGrab
import directkeys
import pyscreenshot

cords = [0,1800, 160,1040]
mousepos = pyautogui.position()
print(mousepos)
green = (106,199,0)
low_red = np.array([161,155,84])
high_red = np.array([179,255,255])
screen = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=cords)
screenrgb = screen.convert('RGB')

while True:
    for y in range(screenrgb.height):
        for x in range(screenrgb.width):
            r, g , b = screenrgb.getpixel(x,y)
            if (r,g,b) == green:
                pyautogui.click(screenrgb.getpixel(x,y))
```